# Consistency on tables with readonly / disabled fields (including inputs, dropdowns and buttons)

Tags: tables, input-fields, disable, consistency

In a table (datatable) I have editable rows as you can see in the mockup.
Under some conditions rows' input, dropdown and button must be readonly or disabled (unchangeable).

The important note here is that **there is no possible action that enables the user to make the inputs editable/the button clickeable.**

The reason for make a row unchangeable is that a medical practice that has has been authorized for X times (to be consumed X times) has been already consumed at least 1 time. 
E.g. you have been authorized for 3 physiotherapy sessions, and you have already used at least 1.

So,

1. What of the following options (or another you can think of) would be
   better for this case?
2. How could I show/represent the "is already consumed" signifier within that rows?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fIlKC1.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: 3 is definitely the way to go.  you may also consider a 3-way toggle button to the top right of the grid with options to show `All`, `Authorized`, `Unauthorized` (default to all)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think 3 is the best option here.

1 & 2 show the form fields and have them disabled, this could indicate to a user that they could become editable - and they may wonder if they need to perform an action to make them editable. Because they will never be editable, no form controls are needed. The data should be printed.

Another thing they may help this UI: You could return descriptive text or an icon in place of blank areas to indicate this has been 'consumed', as you put it.